# IBM Watson Assistant: How to let the chatbot respond with a dynamic option list

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm on IBM Watson Assistant Web Interface.

I would like to add a possibility for the chatbot to respond with a list of options based on a variable. This variable will be filled by my backend. The variable will be like this :

```php
$list: [

{"value": 443535, "label": "n°443535"},

{"value": 443536, "label": "n°443536"},

{"value": 443537, "label": "n°443537"}

]
```

So I can't use the basic interface.
[image]

I must use the JSON editor.
[image]

But in it, obviously it's impossible to add data (with for example tag) of a type different from type "string". What can I do ?

Comment: What is the user interface? Is there an app in-between that could transform the response? How is the backend connected?

Comment: Nodejs backend, reactjs ui, for the moment i hardcoded a response from the bot, and intercepted response to transform it into button but this is ugly.

Comment: Did you find an answer to solve this ?

Comment: Hi,

no, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

The JSON structure for an IBM Watson Assistant answer with options is documented. You would need to compose a JSON value based on that format and assign it to a variable, e.g., **myvar**.

Now, in your dialog you would need to add that options array myOptionsArray to your output. Assuming the array data is stored in the variable myvar, use something like this:

```
<? output.generic.addAll($myvar.myOptionsArray) ?>
```

The generic refers to the [generic JSON output format](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-responses-json) - in contrast to the integrations JSON format. The above expression could be placed in a response.

Comment: Also see this blog post: https://medium.com/ibm-watson/how-to-dynamically-add-response-options-to-dialog-nodes-in-watson-assistant-e14c5e08beca